# Understanding chain rule for Matrix calculus

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to understand why :
$ \frac{\partial \mathrm{tr}((A\cdot x+b)^\top \cdot (A\cdot x+b))}{\partial x} = 2\cdot A^\top \cdot (b+A\cdot x)$ . A is a matrix, x and b are two vectors.

The chain rule tells us that
$\frac{\partial g(u)}{\partial x}  = \frac{\partial g(u)}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $

Here $u(x) = Ax+b$ and $g(x) = tr(x^\top x) $

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = A^\top $

$\frac{\partial g(u)}{\partial u} =2(Ax+b) $

So I was expecting the result to be $ 2(Ax+b)*A^\top$ . I know that in terms of dimensions it cannot be the correct answer. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: $Ax + b$ is a vector, right? So $(Ax + b)^T(Ax+ b)$ is already a scalar, and the trace isn’t needed at all. We could just take $g(x) = x^T x = \| x \|^2$.

Comment: @littleO It's an exercice.

Comment: Note that if $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ then $F'(x)$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. The mistake in your work is that the derivative of $u(x) = Ax + b$ is $u'(x) = A$, not $u'(x) = A^T$. Also, the derivative of the function $g(y) = y^T y = \| y \|^2$ is $g'(y) = 2 y^T$, which is a row vector rather than a column vector. You are taking the derivative of the function $F(x) = g(u(x))$. By the chain rule, $F'(x) = g'(u(x)) u'(x) = 2(Ax + b)^T A$. That is the correct result for $F'(x)$. If we use the convention that $\nabla F(x)$ is a column vector, then $\nabla F(x) = F'(x)^T = 2A^T (Ax + b)$.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$The chain rule works great for scalar equations, or if you're using index notation. But it sucks when you combine it with matrix/vector notation. It leads to all sorts of errors involving transpositions and mismatched dimensions.

The most reliable way to calculate gradients in matrix/vector notation is via *differentials*.
$$\eqalign{
u &= Ax+b \qiq \c{du=A\,dx} \\
g &= u:u \\
dg &= 2u:\c{du} = \LR{2u:\c{A\,dx}} = 2A^Tu:dx \\
\grad{g}{x} &= 2A^Tu = 2A^T(Ax+b) \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
It is sometimes called the double-dot product or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $({\rm i.e.}\,\;n\!=\!1)\,$
it corresponds to the usual dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in several different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\
\\
}$$

---

You can also approach the problem using index notation. The only gradient that you need to know is the following
$$\eqalign{
\grad{x_i}{x_j} = \delta_{ij}
 = \begin{cases}
\o\quad{\rm if}\;i=j \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
}$$
Then using the Einstein summation convention (wherein a repeated index implies summation over that index), write the equation and calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
u_i &= A_{ij}x_j + b_i \\
\grad{u_i}{x_k} &= A_{ij}\delta_{jk} \;=\; A_{ik} \\
\\
g &= u_i u_i \\
\grad{g}{x_k}
 &= \LR{\grad{u_i}{x_k}}u_i + u_i\LR{\grad{u_i}{x_k}} \\
 &= 2\LR{\grad{u_i}{x_k}}u_i \\
 &= 2A_{ik} u_i \\
 &= 2A_{ki}^T u_i \\
 &= 2A_{ki}^T \LR{A_{ij}x_j + b_i} \\
}$$
which, unsurprisingly, is the same as the previous result.

Comment: “But it sucks when you combine it with matrix/vector notation” I agree that the differential approach is excellent, but, the chain rule extends *beautifully* to vector calculus. If $h:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at $x$ and $g:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^p$ is differentiable at $h(x)$, then $f = g \circ h$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f’(x) = g’(h(x)) h’(x)$.

Comment: @littleO The "sucky" part is that, converting your $g'$ and $h'$ to matrix notation $(G,H)$, there is opportunity for transposition errors when $m=m$ and students must choose between $F=GH,\,F=G^TH,\,F=HG,\,{\rm or}\,F=H^TG$. Don't laugh, it happens all the time. There is a further problem when $x$ is matrix-valued. Then $h'$ becomes a third-order tensor, which is difficult to calculate and manipulate within matrix/vector notation, and is a totally unnecessary complication since $g$ is typically scalar-valued.

Comment: @littleO you are saying that the chain rule extends to vector calculus, and I think that I am applying the formula that you are mentioning in your comment. So where is my mistake ?

Comment: @user1482030 I added a comment below your original question (see above) that points out where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

**Background info:** If $F: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at a point $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then $F'(x)$ is an $m \times n$ matrix.

Since $A$ is a matrix and $x$ and $b$ are vectors, $(Ax + b)^T (Ax + b)$ is a scalar, and there is no need to take the trace. You are taking the derivative of the function $f(x) = \|Ax + b\|^2$. Notice that $f(x) = g(h(x))$, where
$$
h(x) = Ax + b \quad \text{and} \quad g(u) = \|u\|^2.
$$
The derivatives of $h$ and $g$ are $h'(x) = A$ and $g'(u) = 2 u^T$. By the chain rule,
$$
f'(x) = g'(h(x)) h'(x) = 2(Ax + b)^T A.
$$